# React adding fields from a drop down menu

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, drop-down-menu

I'm fairly new to react, and I got involved in this project that was already ongoing, and I was asked to add more fields to a form, after the user chooses how many they want. Basically the form has a couple of fields, and if the user wants to add more people they can choose 1, 2, 3 or 4 and I need them to do so when choosing from a drop down menu, but I'm not sure how to do it. Can I make a div hide or not based on the click from the drop down? here is the code I'm working with.

It could also be one button that adds multiple fields on click one or the other

I've seen a couple of people doing it with redux, but I don't know enough of redux to figure out what they were doing.

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {
  Card, CardBody, Col, Button, Form, FormGroup, Label, Input, UncontrolledDropdown,
  DropdownToggle, DropdownMenu, DropdownItem,
} from 'reactstrap';
import ChevronDownIcon from 'mdi-react/ChevronDownIcon';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import StaticBar from './StaticBar';
import { getBasicQuote } from '../../../redux/actions/quoteActions';
import QuotePanel from './QuotePanel';


class VerticalForm extends PureComponent {
  static propTypes = {
    history: PropTypes.shape({}).isRequired,
    getBasicQuotethis: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  };

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
    };
  }

  handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    const { getBasicQuotethis } = this.props;
    const gender = event.target.elements.gender.value;
    const age = event.target.elements.age.value;
    event.preventDefault();
    getBasicQuotethis(age, gender);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Col md={12} lg={12}>
          <Card>
            <CardBody>
              <div className="card__title">
                <h5 className="bold-text">Quote Tool</h5>
                <h5 className="subhead">Labels are above fields</h5>
              </div>
              <Form className="form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <FormGroup className="form__form-group">
                  <Label className="form__form-group-label" for="registerEmail">Gender</Label>
                  <Input
                    // className="form__form-group-field"
                    type="text"
                    name="gender"
                    id="registerEmail"
                    placeholder="Gender"
                  />
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup className="form__form-group">
                  <Label className="form__form-group-label" for="registerPassword">Age</Label>
                  <Input
                    // className="form__form-group-field"
                    type="text"
                    name="age"
                    id="registerEmail"
                    placeholder="Age"
                  />
                </FormGroup>
                <Button size="sm" className="btn btn-primary" type="Submit">
                  Submit
                </Button>
                <UncontrolledDropdown>
                  <DropdownToggle className="icon icon--right" outline color="primary">
                    <p>Add Dependent <ChevronDownIcon /></p>
                  </DropdownToggle>
                  <DropdownMenu className="dropdown__menu">
                    <DropdownItem>1</DropdownItem>
                    <DropdownItem>2</DropdownItem>
                    <DropdownItem>3</DropdownItem>
                    <DropdownItem divider />
                    <DropdownItem>4 +</DropdownItem>
                  </DropdownMenu>
                </UncontrolledDropdown>
              </Form>
            </CardBody>
          </Card>
        </Col>
        <StaticBar />
        <QuotePanel />
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(null, { getBasicQuotethis: getBasicQuote })(VerticalForm);
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I figure it out how to do it.

```
class VerticalForm extends PureComponent {
  static propTypes = {
    history: PropTypes.shape({}).isRequired,
    getBasicQuotethis: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  };

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      showHideDependentSpouse: false,
      showHideDependent2: false,
      showHideDependent3: false,
      showHideDependent4: false,
    };
    this.hideComponent = this.hideComponent.bind(this);
  }

  handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    const { getBasicQuotethis } = this.props;
    const gender = event.target.elements.gender.value;
    const age = event.target.elements.age.value;
    event.preventDefault();
    getBasicQuotethis(age, gender);
  }


  hideComponent(name) {
    switch (name) {
      case 'showHideDependentSpouse':
        this.setState(prevState => ({ showHideDependentSpouse: !prevState.showHideDependentSpouse }));
        break;
      case 'showHideDependent2':
        this.setState(prevState => ({ showHideDependent2: !prevState.showHideDependent2 }));
        break;
      case 'showHideDependent3':
        this.setState(prevState => ({ showHideDependent3: !prevState.showHideDependent3 }));
        break;
      case 'showHideDependent4':
        this.setState(prevState => ({ showHideDependent4: !prevState.showHideDependent4 }));
        break;
      default:
    }
  }

  render() {
    const {
      showHideDependentSpouse, showHideDependent2, showHideDependent3, showHideDependent4,
    } = this.state;
    return (
      <>
        <Col md={12} lg={12}>
          <Card>
            <CardBody>
              <div className="card__title">
                <h5 className="bold-text">Quote Tool</h5>
                <h5 className="subhead">Labels are above fields</h5>
              </div>
              <Form className="form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <FormGroup className="form__form-group">
                  <Label className="form__form-group-label" for="registerEmail">Gender</Label>
                  <Input
                    // className="form__form-group-field"
                    type="text"
                    name="gender"
                    id="registerEmail"
                    placeholder="Gender"
                  />
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup className="form__form-group">
                  <Label className="form__form-group-label" for="registerPassword">Age</Label>
                  <Input
                    // className="form__form-group-field"
                    type="text"
                    name="age"
                    id="registerEmail"
                    placeholder="Age"
                  />
                  <div>
                    {showHideDependentSpouse && <DependentSpouse />}
                    {showHideDependent2 && <Dependent1 />}
                    {showHideDependent3 && <Dependent1 />}
                    {showHideDependent4 && <Dependent4 />}
                  </div>
                </FormGroup>
                <Button size="sm" className="btn btn-primary" type="Submit">
                  Submit
                </Button>
                <Row>
                  <Col lg={8}>
                    <p>Check each box to add the respective number of dependents</p>
                  </Col>
                  <Col>
                    <Label check>
                      <Input type="checkbox" onClick={() => this.hideComponent('showHideDependentSpouse')} />
                    </Label>
                  </Col>
                  <Col>
                    <Label check>
                      <Input type="checkbox" onClick={() => this.hideComponent('showHideDependent2')} />
                    </Label>
                  </Col>
                  <Col>
                    <Label check>
                      <Input type="checkbox" onClick={() => this.hideComponent('showHideDependent3')} />
                    </Label>
                  </Col>
                  <Col>
                    <Label check>
                      <Input type="checkbox" onClick={() => this.hideComponent('showHideDependent4')} />
                    </Label>
                  </Col>
                </Row>
              </Form>
            </CardBody>
          </Card>
        </Col>
        <StaticBar />
        <QuotePanel />
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(null, { getBasicQuotethis: getBasicQuote })(VerticalForm);
```

Basically set the state for each of the components i want to render, made individual components aside, and then made a logic to change the state false or true, then created a condition on each to check if the state is true.

Hopefully this will be helpful for someone.